# Optical flow with opencv. CPU and GPU give highly different results

Tags: python, opencv, opticalflow

I'm using OpenCV to calculate the optical flow between two images. I used to use use `cv2.optflow.createOptFlow_DualTVL1()` to calculate it previously. Now I'm trying to replicate the results using cuda. I've tried several optical flow algorithms on CUDA and they all give vastly different results. Some even by order of magnitude.

Am I using it wrong? Or if it's intended that way(which I strongly doubt), which two algorithms (CPU, GPU) will consistently give the same results?

Some code below:

```
optical_flow = cv2.optflow.createOptFlow_DualTVL1()
optical_flow_gpu_0 = cv2.cuda.FarnebackOpticalFlow_create()

H,W = prev.shape[:2]
params = {'perfPreset':cv2.cuda.NvidiaOpticalFlow_2_0_NV_OF_PERF_LEVEL_SLOW,
          'outputGridSize':cv2.cuda.NvidiaOpticalFlow_2_0_NV_OF_OUTPUT_VECTOR_GRID_SIZE_1} # Changing this param produces different results but they are still too large flow-vectors.
optical_flow_gpu_1 = cv2.cuda.NvidiaOpticalFlow_2_0_create((W,H),**params)



prev = imgs_gray_batch[0]
curr = imgs_gray_batch[1]

prev_gpu = cv2.cuda_GpuMat(prev)
curr_gpu = cv2.cuda_GpuMat(curr)

flow_cpu = optical_flow.calc(prev,curr,None)

flow_gpu_cuda = optical_flow_gpu_0.calc(prev_gpu, curr_gpu, None)
flow_gpu0 = flow_gpu_cuda.download().astype(np.float32)
flow_gpu_cuda = optical_flow_gpu_1.calc(prev_gpu, curr_gpu, None)
flow_gpu1 = flow_gpu_cuda[0].download().astype(np.float32)
```

```
def max_rho(flow):
    #flow = flow.download().astype(np.float32)
    fx,fy = np.split(flow,2,axis=2)
    f_rho = np.sqrt(fx*fx + fy*fy)
    max_rho = f_rho.max()
    print(max_rho)

max_rho(flow_cpu)
max_rho(flow_gpu0)
max_rho(flow_gpu1)
-------------------------------
# The max value of flows are of different magnitude... 
2.4124358
3.2447324
64.0
```

And some images

```
plt.figure(figsize = (20,20))
plt.subplot(1,6,1)
plt.imshow(flow_cpu[:,:,0], cmap = 'hot', interpolation = 'nearest')
plt.colorbar()

plt.subplot(1,6,2)
plt.imshow(flow_cpu[:,:,1], cmap = 'hot', interpolation = 'nearest')
plt.colorbar()

plt.subplot(1,6,3)
plt.imshow(flow_gpu0[:,:,0], cmap = 'hot', interpolation = 'nearest')
plt.colorbar()

plt.subplot(1,6,4)
plt.imshow(flow_gpu0[:,:,1], cmap = 'hot', interpolation = 'nearest')
plt.colorbar()

plt.subplot(1,6,5)
plt.imshow(flow_gpu1[:,:,0], cmap = 'hot', interpolation = 'nearest')
plt.colorbar()

plt.subplot(1,6,6)
plt.imshow(flow_gpu1[:,:,1], cmap = 'hot', interpolation = 'nearest')
plt.colorbar()
print('Max')
```

[image: heatmaps]

This part of OpenCV is very poorly documented so not sure what to do.

Comment: Did you read the docs, whether createOptFlow_DualTVL1 is the same algorithm as FarnebackOpticalFlow_create ? There are tons of different algorithms for Optical Flow estimation.

Comment: I understand how different algorithms can yield slightly different results, however, they shouldn't give results different by a magnitude of 10 as optical flow is a well-defined problem.

Comment: Unfortunately OpenCV's docs on optical flow a re fairly basic  so it's hard to figure out the key differences between algorithms.

Comment: Optical Flow is not a solved problem, the it could be possible that the one or the other algorithm makes mistakes. But there are also a lot of different possible reasons.

Comment: OpenCV contains *implementations* of these algorithms. if you want to learn about the algorithms, follow the references given in OpenCV docs and read the original publications.

Comment: Wow... that never came to me. Even better, I could just read through their source code. Why even have StackOverflow. \s

Comment: How did you install cv2? My installed package doesn't have  cv2.cuda.FarnebackOpticalFlow_create

Answer (score 0):

The optical flow algorithm you used were different, and some of the optical flow algorithms in opencv did return different results from the same input data. And I think this may be the problem the cpu and gpu gives different results. If u want to check cpu and gpu results, you should at least use the same input data and same kind of algorithm (like Farneback algorithm of cpu and gpu version).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the `convertToFloat()` function. The raw output produced by cuda_NvidiaOpticalFlow_2_0 is of format CV_16SC2, which needs to be converted back to a float array before its values are intelligible. Use the function as so:

```
sz = 1024
nvof = cv.cuda_NvidiaOpticalFlow_2_0.create((sz,sz), outputGridSize = 4, perfPreset = 5)
im1 = cv.cuda_GpuMat(np.random.rand(sz,sz))
im2 = cv.cuda_GpuMat(np.random.rand(sz,sz))
output = nvof.calc(im1, im2, None, None)
output_cpu = cv.cuda_GpuMat.download(nvof.convertToFloat(output[0], None))
```